# Which pattern or method to use when calling a regex check method in multiple if statements?

Tags: java, regex, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I created a factory pattern in my class.

In this class I injected classes which implements `Command` interface based on incoming String parameter.

**Factory class**

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CommandFactory {
    private final ACommand aCommand;
    private final BCommand bCommand;
    private final CCommand cCommand;
    private final DCommand dCommand;
    private final ECommand eCommand;
    private final FCommand fCommand;

    public Command createCommand(String content) {
        if (aCommand.isMatching(content)) {
            return aCommand;
        } else if (bCommand.isMatching(content)) {
            return bCommand;
        } else if (cCommand.isMatching(content)) {
            return cCommand;
        } else if (dCommand.isMatching(content)) {
            return dCommand;
        } else if (eCommand.isMatching(content)) {
            return eCommand;
        } else if (fCommand.isMatching(content)) {
            return fCommand;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

In `isMatching()` method there are different regex'es and I try to figure out how this incoming String should be processed.

I am looking for a cleaner way to get rid of these sequential if statements. Because whenever I create a new class into this factory I add another if statement.

Comment: This is what a factory pattern looks like.  It may look ugly, but elsewhere in your code you can code to an interface and not worry about it.  I'm not sure there is a way to improve things.

Comment: Don't. Use a proper lexical analyser.

Comment: Well, you can introduce switch statement instead of multiple ifs, code will become a bit cleaner. Other than that, factory pattern as it is.

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov Well you can't actually. What exactly were you planning to switch on?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @EJP Can you please show me the way how to use a lexical analyser for this situation. What should I replace with lexical analyser and how should I start with it?

Comment: @EJP I was referring to Pattern.quote(String s) API. Will post example as an answer.

Comment: Create a map, let the commands add themselves to it and return the instance from there.

Comment: @rsp What do you mean by "add themselves to it"?

Comment: @ahmetcetin Using code like `command.addTo(map)` so that your factory code doesn't have to know the labels under which the command is known to the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `Stream` can help?

```
Stream<Command> stream = Stream.of(aCommand, bCommand, cCommand ...);
return stream.filter(x -> x.isMatching(content)).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Now every time you add a new class, you just add a new object to the first line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the sequential if statements you can use streams (like user [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50837612/2735286) suggested) or loops and I would also suggest to return and optional which makes `null` handling clearer for the client.

Here are two suggested options to get rid of `if else` repetitions one with loops another with streams:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class CommandPatternExample {

    private List<Command> candidates = Arrays.asList(new ACommand(), new BCommand(), new CCommand());

    public Optional<Command> createCommand(String content) {
        for(Command command : candidates) {
            if(command.isMatching(content)) {
                return Optional.of(command);
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public Optional<Command> createCommandStream(String content) {
        return candidates.stream().filter(c -> c.isMatching(content)).findFirst();
    }
}

interface Command<T> {
    void execute(T obj);
    boolean isMatching(String s);
}

class ACommand implements Command<String> {

    @Override
    public void execute(String obj) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMatching(String s) {
        return "A".equals(s);
    }
}

class BCommand implements Command<String> {

    @Override
    public void execute(String obj) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMatching(String s) {
        return "B".equals(s);
    }
}

class CCommand implements Command<String> {

    @Override
    public void execute(String obj) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMatching(String s) {
        return "C".equals(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map might be a good idea. Meaning if you place your command instances into a map as values where your key would be something that you could match against incoming String. Then instead of sequential search with Efficiency O(n) you can get much better performance O(1). This is a short answer.

Besides that There is an open source java library MgntUtils (wriiten by me) that contains some utility called "Self-instantiating factories" Basically it manages and the Factory for you. All you will need to do is to create a class that implements a certain interface and the utility will add it for you into a map based factory. It might be useful to you. Here is the [link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/) to an article that explains about the utilities in the library as well as where to get the library (Github and Maven central). In the article look for the paragraph "**Lifecycle management (Self-instantiating factories)**". Also library comes with a detailed written javadoc and code example for that feature.